# Why border-bottom does not work with tr without border-collapse?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tr

I just see the solution in StackOverflow to set border-bottom with tr, but I do not understand why CSS automatically hides the cell borders.

I try to apply borders to the cells without border-collapse and I can see in the CSS box source code it has a border but on the webpage is like hidden by something, what is that? And why that happens?

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-head {
  background: white;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: red;
}

td {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #808080;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/table.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr class="table-head">
          <th>Class Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
          <th>Trainer</th>
          <th>Spots</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Like a butterfly</td>
          <td>Boxing</td>
          <td>9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td>Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mind &amp; Body</td>
          <td>Yoga</td>
          <td>8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td>Adam Stewart</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Wheel Pose Full Posture</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">7:00 AM - 8:30 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Playful Dancer's Flow</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Zumba Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Cardio Blast</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Pilates Reformer</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Supple Spine and Shoulders</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">6:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Yoga for Divas</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Virtual Cycle</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Like a butterfly</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Boxing</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Mind &amp; Body</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Adam Stewart</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Crit Cardio</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Wheel Pose Full Posture</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">7:00 AM - 8:30 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Playful Dancer's Flow</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Zumba Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Cardio Blast</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Pilates Reformer</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Supple Spine and Shoulders</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">6:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Yoga for Divas</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Virtual Cycle</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ByrisettiHemanth there you go.

Comment: I just want the explanation of why when border-collapse is tossed off, the cell borders are hidden by something but it appears in the CSS box source code.

Comment: The spec requires that borders on rows  (along with columns, row groups and column groups) are ignored in the [separated borders model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#separated-borders). It doesn't explain why it's necessary.

Comment: Makes sense but declaring border-collapse, the rows appear with their border, so exist an exception with the ["User-Agent must ignore"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#ignore)?

Comment: No, the [collapsing border model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#collapsing-borders) just has different rules entirely.

Comment: @Alohci I suppose is [The collapsing border model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#collapsing-borders) is making it possible to set borders to rows, right? Because it says "In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column group".

Answer (score 1):

if you want your cells have border, you should  set border or border-bottom for them and then for colapse, border-collapse = collapse. also you can set border for your tr and table like this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-head {
background: white;
font-family: Lato;
font-weight: 700;
color: red;
}

td {
font-family: Lato;
font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

tr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0 auto;
background: white;
border-radius: 1px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr class="table-head">
          <th>Class Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
          <th>Trainer</th>
          <th>Spots</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Like a butterfly</td>
          <td>Boxing</td>
          <td>9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td>Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mind &amp; Body</td>
          <td>Yoga</td>
          <td>8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td>Adam Stewart</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Wheel Pose Full Posture</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">7:00 AM - 8:30 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Playful Dancer's Flow</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Zumba Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Cardio Blast</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Pilates Reformer</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Supple Spine and Shoulders</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">6:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Yoga for Divas</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Virtual Cycle</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Like a butterfly</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Boxing</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Mind &amp; Body</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Adam Stewart</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Crit Cardio</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Aaron Chapman</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Wheel Pose Full Posture</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">7:00 AM - 8:30 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Playful Dancer's Flow</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Zumba Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Dance</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Cardio Blast</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">5:00 PM - 7:00 PM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Pilates Reformer</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Supple Spine and Shoulders</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">6:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Yoga for Divas</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Yoga</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">9:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Donna Wilson</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row100 body">
          <td class="cell100 column1">Virtual Cycle</td>
          <td class="cell100 column2">Gym</td>
          <td class="cell100 column3">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</td>
          <td class="cell100 column4">Randy Porter</td>
          <td class="cell100 column5">20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```